# What is the longest amount of moves before an inevitable checkmate?

Tags: endgame, theory, checkmate

When most pieces are gone, inevitable checkmates often occur and are usually presented in the form *x* moves until checkmate. However, what is the biggest valid possibility of *x*. (*By valid I mean that it is possible to get to in a game.*)